# Open, wait, save, close, and copy a file using Windows batch file commands

Tags: batch-file, cmd

With my `.bat` I would like to:

- open the xlsx file,
- waiting 2 min,
- close the file with save options
- copy this file to another folder.

For now I can copy and paste the file, but I don't know how to open it, with a [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) function, and save it.

Thank you for your help.

My code is :

```
@echo off
cmd "O:\XXXX\*.*"
xcopy/y "O:\XXXX\*.*" "O:\XXX\" 
pause
```

Comment: Why are you wanting to "close the file with save options?" Are you expecting that a user would make changes? Is there something magical about "2 min?"

Comment: @lit I would like to open the file, it will update the results of function, after I close the file saving the changes.

Comment: what is the purpose of this "update?" The next time the document is opened, the cell will be updated again. Right? If you want to set the value in a cell and save it, this can easily be done using the PowerShell `ImportExcel` module or VBS.

Answer (score 2):

Marie in disjointed comments

> I suggested a simpler alternative method to do what you need on this
> occasion is to use a simple command line tool see Orlandos Sendkeys
> Utility (the example is almost what you want to do)
>
> 1. download sendkeys from cpap.com.br/orlando
> 2. see how the demo runs
> 3. open Excel with a blank sheet and at a CMD> run this demo string

`SendKeys.exe 1.5 10 "Microsoft Excel" "Hello!~{PAUSE 2}After 2s.~{PAUSE 2}%(FS)~"`

> 4. adapt to your own version of Excel keys since the %(FS) is ALT File Save in English

you replied

> @KJ Thank you, KJ, unfortunately I can't download Orlando with my PC.

So we continue to doing it in a more dirty fashion, but you **still need a means to save the file** by invoking an autosave which would most easily be done using an extended Excel macro in your source **.xlsm**, anyway after all these changes your non working file should now be replaced in your question as

```
@echo off
start "Excel Running" /MIN EXCEL.EXE "\\XXX\Fichier.xlsm"

REM add a delay of **2 minutes !** whilst sheet recalculates before saving a copy
timeout 120
```

**REM copying a file that has NOT been saved using keys at this point will NOT**

**REM be what you really need to solve your problem unless you use a macro ?**

REM **see Later**

```
xcopy/y "\\XXX\Dossier_avant*.*" "\\XXX\Dossier_apres\"


REM add a 3 second delay to check above worked but is not really needed
timeout 3

REM temporary for debugging. Later just REM it out
 TASKLIST /M |Find /i "exce"

REM this line should be working with either a SUCCESS: or ERROR:
TASKKILL /T /F /IM excel.exe

REM keep this line for seeing errors above, once happy, it can become REM PAUSE
PAUSE
```

I think that **IF you are constrained** (by IT policy) to the command line it is best you write your own autosaving macro, however, MY problem is I don't know if you need it for more than one input.xlsm.

So **save this as OpenRunSaveExit.vbs** in your working folder where your .bat is. There is a reason I did NOT use spaces or `&` in the name for a later step.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
' You may need to include the path to excel.exe if it is a portable version like mine
WshShell.Run "EXCEL.EXE "+"\\XXX\Fichier.xlsm", 9
' 120000 milli-seconds = 2 minutes
WScript.Sleep 120000
' These are the English key combinations for ALT+File+Save . SO alter or remove if not needed
WshShell.SendKeys "%FS"
' These are the English key combinations for ALT+File+eXit . SO alter if needed for French Excel
WshShell.SendKeys "%FX"
' Lets us wait 2 seconds for clean closure
WScript.Sleep 2000
```

**As Peter has pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68302195/10802527)** you need to /WAIT before xcopy and depending on how your vbs file handling is set-up you may not need Wscript in the start line

**NOW replace your .bat** with this

```
@echo off
start /WAIT Wscript OpenRunSaveExit.vbs
xcopy/y "\\XXX\Dossier_avant*.*" "\\XXX\Dossier_apres\"
pause
```

And check it runs without the need for taskkill.

**Finally** why use a 2-4 line .bat, since a desktop shortcut would potentially be easier to use. So make a shortcut for the .vbs file (right click the .vbs, and in English it's Create Shortcut) and wherever it is built move it to your desktop.

Then change the properties like this (where & has a special meaning so the .vbs filename must NOT have spaces or &.)

```
%comspec% /c "start /wait wscript.exe OpenRunSaveExit.vbs & xcopy/y "\\XXX\Dossier_avant*.*" "\\XXX\Dossier_apres\" & pause"
```

P.S. I forgot to add Peter's `start / wait` in this image until later:

[image]

Comment: Note that it's "task**kill**" for a reason (instead of "task**close**"). It just kills Excel. There is no request sent to save anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can't interact with Microsoft Excel (or most of other programs) through Batch unless they provide such an interface. There is however an option to do it [with VBS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24336354/5994041) i.e. via an interface Microsoft Excel supports for interacting with that software.

For just opening the program check [`start`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command e.g.:

```
start /B excel.exe <filename>
```

then you can wait for the user to ***both*** edit and save the file for two minutes or also utilize [`pause`](https://ss64.com/nt/pause.html) if you don't want to introduce a race condition between saving and copying with `xcopy`.

Alternatively use `start` like this:

```
start /WAIT /B excel.exe <filename>
```

so the opened file blocks the operation and once it closes (no edit or saving by the user guaranteed) then it'll unblock and `xcopy` would take place without any time-dependent feature.

Comment: sorry, you mean that I can't open the Excel file with DOS commande ?

Comment: You can *open* it, but you can't interact with the application/file itself this way, therefore there's no guarantee the file would be even modified by the user nor even saved, so there is an opportunity for errors. For interacting directly with the document (i.e. writing values to it, enforcing saving etc) you can use VBS which has bindings into MS Excel program.

Comment: I woud like just open the file and close it after with saving.

Comment: That's the point - you can't do it with Batch (cmd.exe) language because it doesn't know how to do it. You can "open" the file as mentioned in the answer just because `excel.exe` allows a parameter of a filename, or without `excel.exe` directly because the OS knows what to use for files with `.xlsx` at the end. You can't wait for the `save` because MS Excel won't let Batch language know anyhow that such event ever occured, that's why you should either use VBS or block the terminal with `start /WAIT` until MS Excel program stops.

Comment: thank you, how to write start /WAIT commande on .bat file ? I'm beginner on .bat :)

Comment: @Marie It's the second code-block in my answer, just change `<filename>` to your filename.

Comment: thank you, I wrote this : 
start /WAIT /B excel.exe O:\XX\XX\Dossier_avant\*.*

Comment: Do I need to write the name of file please ?

Comment: @Marie yes, a specific filename is necessary, however feel free to try with `*.xlsx` wildcard, perhaps it'll work as well.

Comment: thank you, I wrote this : start /WAIT /B excel.exe O:\XX\Fichier_test.xlsx

Comment: why do you write "B" in start /WAIT /B ?

Comment: @Marie Please check [the manual](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) for the `start` command, it's mentioned in there.

Comment: thank you, the code is works, but my file remains open. How can I close it after the opening for 1 min for example.

Comment: @Marie you can use [`taskkill`](https://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html) in combination with [`sleep`](https://ss64.com/nt/sleep.html).

Comment: thank you. I wrote this :                                                                          
sleep 10
taskkill /F /IM excel.exe      But it seems don't work :(

Comment: Windows does not by default have a `sleep` command or utility. It does however have a `timeout` one, open a Command Prompt window, type `timeout /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read its syntax and usage information. **_Please Note_**, as you seem to have ignored this important information. Batch files cannot interact with your GUI application, so despite all of the assistance you've received in the above answer, you cannot do what you wanted to, using only the batch scripting language. You need a scripting language which can interact with a GUI application, probably by SENDing KEYSrokes.

Comment: @Compo thank you.                                                                                                          I mean by "taskkil doesn't work" is that my file remains open. The line of code is : start /WAIT /B excel.exe "\\XXX\Fichier_.xlsx"
taskkill /f /im excel.exe

Comment: @Compe Normally, with taskkill, my file must be closed, isn't ?

Comment: @KJ  Thank you, KJ, unfortunately I can't download Orlando with my PC.

Comment: @KJ Still not understand why my file remains open.

Comment: @KJ I'll not modify the Excel file manually, I have only the formula =today()

Comment: @KJ so I open the file and I copy the file to another folder :  This code runs well : 
start /WAIT /B excel.exe "\\XXX\Dossier\Fichier.xlsx"

xcopy/y "\\XXX\Dossier_apres\" 
pause

Comment: @KJ but the file remains open, so I added taskkill /im excel.exe after the first line, but the file remains open :(

Comment: my code is : @echo off

start /WAIT /B excel.exe "\\XXX\Dossier\Fichier.xlsx"
timeout 15
taskkill /f /im excel.exe 
xcopy/y "\\XXX\Dossier\*.*" "\\XXXX\Dossier\" 
pause

Comment: The only function in my file is = today()

Comment: @KJ thank you ! How I close the Excel if modified file is open please ?

Comment: @echo off

start /WAIT /B excel.exe "\\XXX\Fichier.xlsm"
xcopy/y "\\XXX\Dossier_avant\*.*" "\\XXX\Dossier_apres\" 
tasklist /m |find /i "exce"
taskkill /f /im excel.exe
pause

Comment: But I have the same problem

Comment: ahem - what do you think opening and closing the file does to `=today()`? Replace it with the current date? No. It's a function (comparable to a variable like `%date%` in a batch script) which won't change. After opening and closing it's still `%date%` in the script and `=today()` in an Excel file.